# I cant add items in list inside foreach loop how to solve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I tried to add an item in myList inside foreach loop:
    I summarized the problem, Let's consider the EmployeeInfo has 1000 records then the HasValue did not adding items.

```
List<bool> HasValue = new List<bool>();

foreach(var list in EmployeeInfo)
{
 if(list.Count() > 0)
   {
     HasValue.Add(true);
   }
  else 
   {
     HasValue.Add(false);
   }

}
```

Comment: what will be the checker of `list` to know that it will add to the `HasValue`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to be **super explicit** about the **exact** contents you want `HasValue` to have at the end of execution of your [mcve].

Comment: What is the definition of EmployeeInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you get closer to your answer?

```
    public class EmployeeInfo {
        public List<String> TheList { get; } = new List<String>();
    }

    public void Test(){
        var employeeInfo = new EmployeeInfo();
        var hasValues = employeeInfo.TheList.Count( list => list.Any() );
        var noValues = employeeInfo.TheList.Count - hasValues;
    }
```